# Define a customizable (defcustom) key binding

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, defcustom

I want to allow the user to redefine key bindings for the interactive commands in a major mode. I tried putting them in strings, but I can't get the customized variable value in my mode-map. Here's what I tried:

In the init file:

```el
(require 'myfeature)

(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(myfeature-kb-configure "C-c C-u"))
```

In `myfeature.el`:

```el
(defcustom myfeature-kb-configure "C-c C-p"
  "Plop."
  :type 'string
  :group 'myfeature-mode-keyboard-shortcuts)

(defvar myfeature-mode-map
   (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
     (define-key map (kbd myfeature-kb-configure) 'myfeature-conf) ; => "C-c C-p"
     map)
   "Keymap for `myfeature-mode'.")

;;;###autoload
(define-derived-mode myfeature-mode prog-mode "myfeature" 
"Myfeature mode"
  (kill-all-local-variables)
  (message "key: %s" myfeature-kb-configure) ; => "C-c C-u"
  (use-local-map myfeature-mode-map)
  (run-hooks 'change-major-mode-after-body-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook))

(provide 'myfeature)
```

Apparently, I'm defining `myfeature-mode-map` too early for the mode to pick up the "customized" value ; I get the *old* value, `C-c C-p` in the mode-map, because anywhere else in the file (including in the mode definition) I get the *customized* value. How can I ensure that the customized value gets read every time?

**Nota bene:**

Ideally, I would present to the user a menu with a fixed list (`choice`) of my  commands and a field next to it to input proper key bindings (not `string`), already properly filled with default values so he/she would understand right away what to do, but I don't know how to do that, and found no example of such a marvel.

Comment: This is a nice idea, but you might want to consider that some Emacs users don't like the customize interface, and prefer to set up their config with setq and define-key etc. This will be harder to manage if your mode explicitly over-rides keybindings they have set elsewhere.

Comment: @Tyler Good point. Another problem to solve :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want Customize (or `custom-set-variables` or `customize-set-variable`) to not only change the value of the option but also define that new key value in the keymap then you need to use a `:set` function in your `defcustom`:

```el
(defcustom myfeature-kb-configure "C-c C-p"
  "Plop."
  :type 'string
  :set (lambda (sym defs)
         (custom-set-default sym defs)
         (define-key myfeature-mode-map (kbd myfeature-kb-configure) 'myfeature-conf))
  :group 'myfeature-mode-keyboard-shortcuts)
```

But note that in that `:set` function I hard-coded the command to bind to the key.

---

A different approach, which I've taken in [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles), is this:

1. Provide an option (actually, I use several, for different keymaps and different kinds/groups of keys) whose value is a list of keys and commands to bind to them.
2. In the mode command (`icicle-mode`), use the option to bind the keys to the commands.  In my case, the mode is a minor mode, but the idea is the same.

The relevant code for defining the option(s) is in [`icicles-opt.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/icicles-opt.el).
For example:

```el
(defcustom icicle-top-level-key-bindings
  `(((kbd "<pause>")  icicle-switch-to/from-minibuffer  t)
    ((kbd "C-c `")    icicle-search-generic             t)
    ((kbd "C-c $")    icicle-search-word                t)
    ...)
  "Doc..."
  :type  '(repeat icicle-key-definition)
  :set (lambda (sym defs)
         (custom-set-default sym defs)
         (when (boundp 'icicle-mode-map) ; Avoid error on initialization.
           (icicle-bind-top-level-commands defs)))
  :initialize #'custom-initialize-default
  :group 'Icicles-Key-Bindings)
```

The code that binds the keys in the keymap(s) is in [`icicles-mode.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/icicles-mode.el).  The mode command (`icicle-mode`) calls the function `icicle-bind-top-level-commands`, which binds the keys to the commands.  (The same function is used in the `defcustom` `:set` function.)

Actually, such key-binding options allow for a third field, besides the key and the command to bind to it: a Boolean expression that is used to control whether the binding should be made.  In the case shown above, the expression was always `t`, meaning bind the key unconditionally.

And the key part of the binding description can, instead of a key, be a command to remap to the command to be bound.  Here's an example where the binding description says to remap command `bmkp-bookmark-set-confirm-overwrite` to command `icicle-bookmark-cmd`, if the former command is defined:

```el
(bmkp-bookmark-set-confirm-overwrite             ; Command to remap
 icicle-bookmark-cmd                             ; Command to use in the mode
 (fboundp 'bmkp-bookmark-set-confirm-overwrite)) ; Condition for remapping
```

The `:type` for such an key-bindings option is `(repeat icicle-key-definition)`.  That type widget is defined this way:

```el
(define-widget 'icicle-key-definition 'lazy
  "Key definition type for Icicle mode keys.
A list of three components: KEY, COMMAND, CONDITION, that represents
an `icicle-mode-map' binding of COMMAND according to KEY, if CONDITION
evaluates to non-nil.

KEY is either a key sequence (string or vector) or a command.
COMMAND is a command.
CONDITION is a sexp.

If KEY is a command, then the binding represented is its remapping to
COMMAND."
  :indent 1 :offset 0 :tag ""
  :type
  '(list
    (choice
     (key-sequence :tag "Key" :value [ignore])
     (restricted-sexp :tag "Command to remap" :match-alternatives (symbolp) :value ignore))
    (restricted-sexp :tag "Command" :match-alternatives (symbolp) :value ignore)
    (sexp :tag "Condition")))
```

That uses `symbolp` instead of `commandp`, in case the library defining the
command is not loaded.

Comment: Wow, thorough answer :) Actually, I only needed to set my key not in the table defun, but to at them to it later, in the major mode defun : `(define-key myfeature-mode-map (kbd myfeature-kb-configure) 'myfeature-configure)`